# curl with wildchars in url

Tags: linux, curl

I have file that ends by `-comps.xml` and has the following form:

```
http://some/url/<sha256sum>-<2 chars>-x86_64-comps.xml
```

sha256sum is alphanumeric string of 65 length.

For example:

```
 http://some/url/0dae8d32824acd9dbdf7ed72f628152dd00b85e4bd802e6b46e4d7b78c1042a3-c6-x86_64-comps.xml
```

How I can download this file using `curl`?

Comment: Where are the wildcards in the URL that you mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution using wget:

```
 wget --recursive --level=1 --no-parent --no-directories  --accept '*-comps.xml' --directory-prefix=. http://some/url
```

Comment: Great - would have suggested wget but you had specifically asked for cURL ;-)

Comment: @PassKit I was not locked on curl. Somehow, since curl is more modern utility, I though if there's no way to do it is with it, than cirtanly no way to achive it with wget. Apparrently it's not true, so curl is not replacment of wget.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you already know the filename, to download the contents of the file, then simply use

```
curl -O http://some/url/0dae8d32824acd9dbdf7ed72f628152dd00b85e4bd802e6b46e4d7b78c1042a3-c6-x86_64-comps.xml
```

If you are looking to somehow predetermine the file name based on an SHA256 of the file's contents, then you will need to either already have access to these contents to be able to determine the SHA256 part of the URL, or to have access to an alternative source for this information.

Comment: I'd like to search the file by it's fix end file name, since the start of file name changes from url to url

Comment: The site has to provide some way to look up URLs, there's no automatic way to do it. The site probably has an API for it.

Comment: @dimba, as Barmar says, it will be impossible for you to determine the start of the filename without first having access to the file, or by getting the SHA256 from an alternative source such as a URL lookup API provided by the site. The party that originally uploaded the file could also have this info.